# generating numbered markers

Tags: google-maps

I am looking for numbered markers.
and manually creating marker numbered from 1-1000 is quite laborious.

Is there are better way to upload an image and the program generated 1000 images from that numbered from 1 to 1000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some options:

- [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/)
- [numbered markers from 0 - 300](http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/numbers-letters/) (found with a little googling)
- [numbered markers from 0 - 999](http://silverpeaks.de/blog/?p=387) (more googling)

Comment: StyledMarker also calls the deprecated Google Chart API, only the URL is slightly different: chart.apis.google.com instead of chart.googleapis.com. There was a PHP and image library blog post I found but can't find the link right now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Dynamic Icons](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons) of `Google Chart API`, and get customized markers for your map.

You can use for example this pattern for marker's icon:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=*number*|FF776B|000000
```

and the usage could be this:

```
var number = 15; //
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
    position: latlngOfMarker,   
    map: map,  
    icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+number+'|FF776B|000000'
});
```

The icon will be like this: [image]

However, note that the *service is deprecated* ,and it will not be suitable for long term projects.

Comment: Probably better not to use [that API](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/infographics/) on new projects, it is deprecated: Important: The Infographics portion of Google Chart Tools has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy.

Comment: @geocodezip: Good catch! but  "as per our deprecation policy" means it should continue to work for at least 3 years. Pity about the deprecation though. I'm using it in a couple of mashups.

Comment: They changed the depreciation policy to 1 year (see the [Terms of Use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)).

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks, for the option. I didn't release that.I made changes in my answer.