# Google maps icon color

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Currently you can use googles chart api to load custom markers with different colors

See here: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons

But this has been deprecated. So to ensure that my website works in the future what should I be using?

Or is there some simple way of defining the color of the markers using css or something?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a deprecated library I found http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#StyledMarker which works perfectly :)

Comment: That library uses the charts api under the covers: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=', see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362393/generating-numbered-markers

Comment: buggers. Hmm. I will have a look